# Working with a json file with 2 or no values in a for loop

Tags: json, web-scraping, julia

I'm a R user and I have been trying to scrape a website with Julia.

In this webscraping I downloaded a JSON file and using a `JSON.parse`.

Like this:

```
using HTTP

url = "https://www3.bcb.gov.br/informes/rest/pessoasJuridicas?cnpj=1439107"
response = HTTP.get(url)
dcoop = JSON.parse(String(response.body))
```

In this case, I have the field "classeCooperativa" with two items (id and name).

```
    "classeCooperativa" => Dict{String, Any}("id" => 2, "nome" => "Singular")
```

But with another URL:

```
    url = "https://www3.bcb.gov.br/informes/rest/pessoasJuridicas?cnpj=3795072"
    response = HTTP.get(url)
    dcoop = JSON.parse(String(response.body))
```

I have the field "classeCooperativa" with nothing.

```
   "classeCooperativa" => nothing
```

How can I work with this, since some URL are nothing or with two items?

I have been trying to use a for loop:
(look at classe line)

```
cnpj = [3795072, 1439107]

 for i in 1:length(cnpj)

    url = "https://www3.bcb.gov.br/informes/rest/pessoasJuridicas?cnpj=$(cnpj[i])"
    response = HTTP.get(url)
    dcoop = JSON.parse(String(response.body))

    # Extracting information
    info_gerais_coop_i = DataFrame(
    cnpj_coop = cnpj[i],
    nome_coop = dcoop["nome"],
    naturezaJuridica = String(get(dcoop, "naturezaJuridica", missing)),
    classe = get(get(get(dcoop, "classeCooperativa", NA), "nome", NA), 1),
    situacao = String(get(dcoop, "situacao", missing)),
    regimeEspecial = dcoop["regimeEspecial"],
    logradouro = String(get(get(dcoop, "endereco", missing), "logradouro", missing)),
    complemento = String(get(get(dcoop, "endereco", missing), "complemento", missing)),
    bairro = String(get(get(dcoop, "endereco", missing), "bairro", missing)),
    municipio = String(get(get(get(dcoop, "endereco", missing), "municipio", missing), "nome", missing)),
    uf = String(get(get(get(dcoop, "endereco", missing), "municipio", missing), "siglaEstado", missing)),
    cep = String(get(get(dcoop, "endereco", missing), "cep", missing)),
    endereco_eletronico = String(get(get(dcoop, "endereco", missing), "email", missing)),
    email = String(get(get(dcoop, "endereco", missing), "email", missing)),
    segmento_prudencial = get(dcoop, "segmentoPrudencial", missing),
    #filiacao = get(dcoop, "filiacoesCooperativaCentral", missing)
)

    # Check if info_gerais_coop_i exists and merge

    if isempty(info_gerais_coop)
        info_gerais_coop = copy(info_gerais_coop_i)
    else
        info_gerais_coop = vcat(info_gerais_coop, info_gerais_coop_i)
        info_gerais_coop_i = nothing
    end
        

end
```

Comment: you can just use isnothing()

Comment: @Mark please, can you give more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `isnothing()` to find the no values ones, and `continue` to skip them:

```
cnpj = [3795072, 1439107]

 for i in 1:length(cnpj)
    url = "https://www3.bcb.gov.br/informes/rest/pessoasJuridicas?cnpj=$(cnpj[i])"
    response = HTTP.get(url)
    dcoop = JSON.parse(String(response.body))
    if isnothing(dcoop["classeCooperativa"])
        continue # skip to the next one in cnpj
    end
    # ...the rest of the code... 
end
```

##### Update:

It turns out looking for nothings is unnecessary:

```
using HTTP, DataFrames, JSON

cnpj = [3795072, 1439107]
cs = ["cnpj", "naturezaJuridica", "situacao", "regimeEspecial", "logradouro", "complemento", "bairro", "municipio", "siglaEstado", "cep", "email", "segmentoPrudencial", "filiacao"]
info_gerais_coop = DataFrame()

for c in cnpj
    url = "https://www3.bcb.gov.br/informes/rest/pessoasJuridicas?cnpj=$c"
    response = HTTP.get(url)
    dcoop = JSON.parse(String(response.body))
    dcoops = merge(dcoop, dcoop["endereco"], dcoop["endereco"]["municipio"])
    new = DataFrame(filter(((k,v),) -> k in cs, dcoops))
    new[!, :nome_coop] = [dcoop["nome"]]
    new[!, :municipio] = [dcoop["endereco"]["municipio"]["nome"]]
    new[!, :classe] = [!isnothing(dcoop["classeCooperativa"]) ? dcoop["classeCooperativa"]["nome"] : nothing]
    info_gerais_coop = [info_gerais_coop;new]
end
```

Output:

```
2×15 DataFrame
 Row │ bairro          cep       cnpj     complemento  email                              filiacao  logradour ⋯
     │ String          String    Int64    String       String                             Nothing   String    ⋯
─────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ JARDIM LINDOIA  91010003  3795072  6. ANDAR     confederacao_unicad@sicredi.com.…            AV. ASSIS ⋯
   2 │ VILA OPERÁRIA   17340000  1439107               barracred@barracred.com.br                   RUA ANTON
                                                                                              9 columns omitted
```

Comment: But I need to save the info about cnpj with  "classeCooperativa" => nothing . I need to save something like: classe = NA (in R).

Comment: In R, I just used: `classe = purrr::pluck(dcoop, "classeCooperativa", "nome", .default = NA) ` and worked for both situations.

Comment: ah okay. I don't think NA is a thing in Julia. It uses Nothing or missing

Comment: I added updated code. There were a lot of checks in there for missing values which (at least based on the two examples) were unnecessary. Of course, if elements of dcoop other than classeCooperativa are missing in other examples, then you would do something similar to what I have done with classeCooperativa :-)